# hexadecimal notations for ggplot default colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot to make a scatter plot

I use this command

```
    ggplot(df,aes(x=meanwt, y=meanko,color=threshold)) + geom_point(size=1) + geom_smooth(method=lm,se=FALSE)+
theme_classic()
```

This creates a scatter plot in 2 colors based on my `threshold` column in the file. How can I get the hexadecimal notations for those colors??

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53226282/4836511) answers your question? --> [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the data is not available, the following example is based on open dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
gplot <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy, colour = class)) +
  geom_point(size=1) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE) +
  theme_classic()
gplot
```

[image]

You could get the hexadecimal notations of those colors as:

```
unique(ggplot_build(gplot)$data[[1]]["colour"])
```

Output:

```
    colour
1  #C49A00
16 #53B400
19 #FB61D7
24 #F8766D
38 #00C094
49 #00B6EB
91 #A58AFF
```